# ModRewrite Escape Special Characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For some reason I have some links coming to my domain at: `http://www.domain.com/$!`

I want to 301 redirect those to the root domain.

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^\$\!$ / [L.R=301]
```

But received a 500 error.  Any ideas on how to escape these characters properly?

Comment: First, is the "`L.R=301`" just a typo here or in your config too? (Should be "`L,R=301`"). One approach to try would be to include the characters in a bracket expression like: `RewriteRule ^[$!]+$ / [L, R=301]` ... I don't think they need to be escaped within the brackets, though I may be mistaken about that.

Comment: I feel silly....the period instead of comma was the problem.  I completely missed that typo.   Thank you!